# Problems in implementing the integral image in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I tried to implement the integral image in MATLAB by the following:

```
im = imread('image.jpg');  
ii_im = cumsum(cumsum(double(im)')');
```

`im` is the original image and `ii_im` is the integral image.

The problem here is the value in `ii_im` flows out of the 0 to 255 range.
When using `imshow(ii_im)`, I always get a very bright image which I am not sure is the correct result.  Am I correct here?

Comment: You could also use `cumsum(cumsum(double(im),1),2)` instead of the transposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're implementing the integral image calculations right, but I don't understand why you would want to visualize it - especially since the sums will go beyond any normal integer range.  This is expected as you are performing a summation of intensities bounded by larger and larger rectangular neighbourhoods as you move to the bottom right of the image. It is inevitable that you will get large numbers towards the bottom right. Also, you will obviously get a white image when trying to show this image because most of the values will go beyond 255, which is visualized as white.

If I can add something, one small optimization I have is to get rid of the transposing and use `cumsum` to specify the dimension you want to work on.  Specifically, you can do this:

```
ii_im = cumsum(cumsum(double(im), 1), 2);
```

It doesn't matter what direction you specify first (2 then 1, or 1 then 2).  The summation of all pixels within each bounded area, as long as you specify all directions to operate on, should be the same.

Back to your question for display, if you really, really, really really... I mean **really** want to, you can normalize the contrast by doing:

```
imshow(ii_im, []);
```

However, what you should expect is a gradient image which starts to be dark from the top, then becomes brighter when you get to the bottom right of the image.  Remember, each point in the integral image calculates the total summation of pixel intensities bounded by the top left corner of the image to this point, thus forming a rectangle of intensities you need to sum over.  Therefore, as we move further down and to the right of the integral image, the total summation should increase.

With the `cameraman.tif` image, this is the original image, as well as it's integral image visualized using the above command:

[image]

[image]

Either way, there is absolutely no reason why you would want to visualize it.  You would use this directly with whatever application requires it (adaptive thresholding, Viola-Jones detector, etc.)

Another option could be applying a `log` operation for each value in the integral image.  Something like:

```
imshow(log(1 + ii_im), []);
```

However, this will make most of the pixels have the same contrast and this is probably not useful.  This is what I get with `cameraman.tif`:

[image]

---

The moral of this story is that you need some sort of contrast normalization so that you can fit all of the values in your integral image within the confines of the data type that is used to display the image on the screen using `imshow`.

Comment: Thanks! :) That was a great help. I am implementing the intgeral image to realise the **viola jones** face detection algorithm. When i use cumsum I am getting values of the order of thousands. So as you say, I can use the obtained integral image in my project. Isn't it... Again, Thank You sooo much for your help :) @rayryeng

Comment: @AmitRaj - Yes you can use it when you're done.  That's a problem with the integral image - it will become much larger as you consider larger resolution images.  BTW, if I have helped you, please consider accepting my answer.  This can be done by clicking on the checkmark icon at the top of my post to the left below the up and down arrows.  This signifies to the StackOverflow community that you no longer need help.  Good luck!